# I have installed FIM portal but I am not the administrator

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have installed FIM Portal and the installation is successful. However, I am unable to view Navigation bar and admin controls on the FI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Sets --> Search for Administrators --> Add your User ID to that set.

Comment: There were issues with Database restore that we had taken. After we pointed to correctly restored database it worked.